# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'Modul1' of undefined

Tags: json

i want to read the data from JSON, but this error comes:

(index):93 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'Modul1' of undefined:

```
<button class="accordion" Tag 2></button>

<div id = "tag2">

fetch('DB.json')
    .then(function(resp) {
        return resp.json();
    })
    .then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
        document.querySelector("#tag2").innerHTML = data.Modul1
    });
```

the Json file:

```
{
  "Modul1": [{
    "Einheit1": [{
        "MentorVideo_1_1_0": "LINK",
        "Erledigt": true
      },
      {
        "HeldenVideo": "LINK",
        "Erledigt": true
      },
      {
        "Fragebogen_1_1_1": "LINK",
        "Erledigt": true
      },
      {
        "Deckblatt1_1_1": "LINK",
        "Erledigt": true
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Try to stop in debugger at the problematic line and look what is your "data" is

Comment: i try and get this error: Exception has occurred: ReferenceError: Cannot read property 'Einheit1' of undefined